# Angular Behavior Subject multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, angular

i need to get values from one component and get them in other one, i want to use behaviorSubject, but i dont get, how to pass 2 arguments in behaviorSubject, iam getting error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

```js
  

  //service
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    interface ICellSelection {
      xId: number;
      yId: number;
    }

    export class plotService {

      public IdsForCellSelection: BehaviorSubject<ICellSelection> = new BehaviorSubject<ICellSelection>(null);

      public setIdsForCellSelection(xItemIndex: number, yItemIndex: number) {
        this.IdsForCellSelection.next(xItemIndex, yItemIndex);
      }

      constructor() { }
    }
```

```js
 // component
    public selectArea() {
         this.store.dispatch(({ payload: [] }));
         this.selectedItems = [this.xItem, this.yItem];
         this.selectionChanged.emit(this.selectedItems);
//here iam trying to send 2 arguments+
         this.plotService.setIdsForCellSelection( this.xItemIndex, this.yItemIndex);
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BehaviourSubject takes one argument and you are trying to pass 2.

So below is not correct:

```
this.IdsForCellSelection.next(xItemIndex, yItemIndex);
```

Instead do this:

```
this.IdsForCellSelection.next({xItemIndex, yItemIndex});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass it around as an object of the defined type. Also if the default `null` isn't required, it'd be more suited to use `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1 instead of `BehaviorSubject`.

**Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

interface ICellSelection {
  xId: number;
  yId: number;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class plotService {  
  public IdsForCellSelection: ReplaySubject<ICellSelection> = new ReplaySubject<ICellSelection>(1);

  public setIdsForCellSelection(xItemIndex: number, yItemIndex: number) {
    this.IdsForCellSelection.next(
      { xId: xItemIndex, yId: yItemIndex } as ICellSelection
    );
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

---

To maintain type coherence across the application, you'd need to define the type in an external file and import it where it's required.

Eg.

**cell-selection.ts**

```js
export interface ICellSelection {
  xId: number;
  yId: number;
}
```

**Component**

```js
import { ICellSelection } from './cell-selection';
...

public selectArea() {
  this.store.dispatch(({ payload: [] }));
  this.selectedItems = [this.xItem, this.yItem];
  this.selectionChanged.emit(this.selectedItems);
  this.plotService.setIdsForCellSelection({
    xId: this.xItemIndex, 
    yId: this.yItemIndex
  } as ICellSelection);
}
```

**Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

import { ICellSelection } from './cell-selection';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class plotService {  
  public IdsForCellSelection: ReplaySubject<ICellSelection> = new ReplaySubject<ICellSelection>(1);

  public setIdsForCellSelection(itemIndex: ICellSelection) {
    this.IdsForCellSelection.next(itemIndex);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also pass as an array, like so:

this.IdsForCellSelection.next([xItemIndex, yItemIndex, ..]);

suggestion
don't use an uppercase when naming a variable and use the '$' as a prefix for observables and subjects, it makes your code more readable throughout future developers

"idsForCellSelection$"